# Why is the iPhone viewport wider than 320px?

Tags: viewport

According to documentation the viewport of Safari in iOS should be 320px wide.  However, our content is displaying with about 30px on either side, so the viewport is about 380px overall.  We've tried using both of the following tags with no change in results:

Even when I use the Web Developer extension for Firefox and I resize the viewport to 320px wide, it's not sizing to 320px.  It's more like 380px.

I've looked at removing all extra margins, padding and defined widths but still, the viewport is not sizing down to 320px.  Any ideas on why this might be?

Comment: I'm not seeing any code examples in your question.  Can you provide?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have set min-width in your css code.